# Cross compile error from Ubuntu 14.04 to raspberry zero (using arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

Tags: linux, pi-zero, cross-compilation, arm, broadcom

I'm trying to cross-compile from my Ubuntu 14.04 (host) to the pi zero. Here is what I've done on host to cross compile a very basic example :

`> apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf` from [here](http://linux-sunxi.org/Toolchain#Debian)

Then created a simple test.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then

```
> arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -marm -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -march=armv6 test.cpp
```

Finally copy and paste the exec on my pi zero, execute it, and get a SEGFAULT error... No way to get more, even with `gdb` option.

I guess this comes from a bad cross compiler option, **the exec seems to be not readable from the *broadcom 2835*** . But I've tried all cross-compiler options (`arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -v`) that could arrange that without successing...

Anyone has already done some cross compilation to the pi zero and could help ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the exec seems to be not readable from the broadcom 2835

Yes, and really the compiler should reject these options:

```
-mtune=arm1176jzf-s -march=armv6
```

Because it can't do that properly.  ARM cross compiler packages for various mainstream linux distros are, as far as I am aware, all ARMv7+.

Something that gets confusing here is the "hard float" bit.  This can distinguish arm1176jzf from earlier ARMv6 implementations; it's the last version of it. After that you have ARMv7, which I believe by definition is hard float, and so that is how [Debian chooses to identify it](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort).  Note that page is linked from the SUNXI wiki page you posted, and includes further qualifications:

> Currently the Debian armhf port requires **at least an ARMv7 CPU** with Thumb-2 and VFP3D16.

That's what their cross compiler is made to target.  Ubuntu follows the same pattern.  It won't work to cross compile for model 1 (single core) pis, with the BCM2835 SoC.

The confusing bit is that this means Debian's `armhf` tag is not the same as the `armhf` tag as used by Raspbian, which is the arm1176jzf implementation of ARMv6.

What you want [is here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I was about to test this tool :)
Hope it will work !
I let you know
Thanks again